# Family sharing not working on any device

Tags: family-sharing

I have an Iphone 5c and Ipad air 2, wife has an Iphone 5c, we set up the family sharing, everything looks right, i even see her name listed in the store and vice versa, but for both of us it says the other person has no purchases. I cant seem to find a reason, I have tried every remedy I could find on apple's site.

Comment: Are both of your Apple IDs set up with the same country?